# Nuget.exe: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, build, nuget, nuget-package-restore

On my build server in my prebuild script I want to get all packages required for the solution.

Why? Because this happens:

```
This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer.
Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105.
The missing file is ..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets.
```

According to [Nuget documentation](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build) package restore should happen as part of the TFS 2013 build - but quite obviously it does not.

I tried to implement this as a prebuild action (custom script execution).
Whenever I try to run nuget on the build server this is what happens:

```
PS D:\ws\more\txs04\Data\Services\MyProject\.nuget> .\nuget.exe
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Obviously a proxy issue. Unfortunately I didn't find any solution for this. I logged on as the build user and changed the proxy settings. I also tried environment variables - and the nuget configuration options. However since I cannot even invoke `nuget.exe config` this is kind of not an option.

**Edit:** I can reproduce this behavior on my development machine (where nuget usually works). `runas /user:dev\tfsbuild powershell` Next I try to execute `nuget.exe` and the above mentioned error occurs. It does not occur if I login with the tfsbuild user however.

Comment: The second I called the network administrator to help me troubleshoot this it magically started working. No clue as to why... will investigate if the problem appears again.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue running the nuget restore command from a target in my build .proj file.

```
 <Target Name="RestorePackages">
   <Exec Command="&quot;$(ToolsHome)NuGet\NuGet.exe&quot; restore &quot;$(SourceHome)SolutionFile.sln&quot;" />
 </Target>
```

I added two additional parameters which resolved the issue for me:
   -NonInteractive 
   -RequireConsent

```
<Target Name="RestorePackages">
  <Exec Command="&quot;$(ToolsHome)NuGet\NuGet.exe&quot; restore &quot;$(SourceHome)SolutionFile.sln&quot; -NonInteractive -RequireConsent " />
</Target>
```

Hope this helps anyone else that runs into this.